# Deleting data from the database by selecting the Id column of type int

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, entity-framework, devexpress

with the code below, I can delete the data I selected on the grid in string type, but I get an error in the codes when trying to delete a data in int type. how should I edit the relevant code?

```
private void btnAracSil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Seçili olan veriyi silmek istediğinize emin misiniz?", "Uyarı!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                string secilen = gridAraclar.GetFocusedRowCellValue(colSase).ToString();
                aracbilgiDal.Delete(context, c => c.Sase == secilen);
                aracbilgiDal.Save(context);
                GetAll();
            }
        }
```

I want to delete the data from the database by selecting the Id column of int type in the row I will select from the grid.

```
secilen =gridAraclar.GetFocusedRowCellValue(colId).ToString();
        FrmAracEkle form = new FrmAracEkle(aracbilgiDal.GetByFilter(context, c => c.Id = secilen));
        form.ShowDialog();
        if (form.saved == true)
        {
            GetAll();
        }
```

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'    NetDesign.BackkOffice

Comment: Unless you tell us the error you are getting, I doubt people will even be able to guess what is wrong.

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Firstly, why are you calling ToString if the value is an int? Secondly, your lambda is preforming an assignment rather than a comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        int secim;
        secim = gridAraclar.GetFocusedRowCellValue(colId).GetHashCode();
        FrmAracEkle form = new FrmAracEkle(aracbilgiDal.GetByFilter(context, c => c.Id == secim));
        form.ShowDialog();
        if (form.saved == true)
        {
            GetAll();
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).